# get Exceptions(and their subtypes) from IMethod

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I´m currently developing an Eclipse plugin  for showing a graph with expeption flows(which method throws the Exception and which method catches the exception).

Question is: I have an IMethod instance and I want to get all the exceptions it throws, but not just their types as String(easily obtained by getExceptionTypes()), because I need their subtypes too. I class instances of these exceptions so that I can get their subtypes. Is it possible?

Comment: Posting as a comment since I don't have any example code in front of me for a good answer... but you need to use Eclipse's pseudo-reflection with stuff like `IType` that knows about types without them being in the current JVM. This is one of the most important mental hurdles to keep in mind because the code in your project is NOT loaded in Eclipse's JVM. So you cannot get `Class` instances for your exceptions, normally. But what you are asking for is possible, just not the way you are hinting at.

Comment: I know I need stuff like IType, but the question is how do I get an IType corresponding to a specific exception thrown by a method when I only have an IMethod?